# jQuery detect how many seconds a mouse stays over element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, mouseevent, mouseover

is there any way to detect how many seconds a mouse pointer stays on an html element?

I would like to retrieve how many seconds a mouse stays over element to put a little delay on a callback event... if is possible :)

i'm trying with a simple for() cycle detecting by a counter :

```
var time_over ; 
$('.bean-active').live('mouseover',function(){  
  id_tag = $(this).attr("id");   
  for(time_over = 1;time_over <= 3000;time_over ++){
      if(time_over == 3000){
         $('.bean-bubble,.bean-bubble img').hide();   
         $('#bean-bubble-'+id_tag+',#bean-bubble-'+id_tag+' img').show();
      }  
  }   
});
```

the problem is that it doesn't works :(

also i would like to bind a mouseleave event, script logic should be:

```
while ( mouseover element count how many time it stays over) 
  if (time == n)
  { do somenthing } 
if (mouseleave from element earlier then time)
{ do somenthing different }
```

Comment: using that now :) but seems timeout doesn't works for me :P

Comment: $('.bean-active').live('mouseover',function(){
 $(this).hoverIntent({
    over: function(){
     id_tag = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).fadeTo(100,0.5).fadeTo(200,1);
    $('.bean-bubble,.bean-bubble img').hide();
    $('#bean-bubble-'+id_tag+',#bean-bubble-'+id_tag+' img').show();

    },
    timeout:900,
    out: function(){
    return false;
    }
});
$(this).trigger('mouseover');
});

Comment: Is it possible to count seconds without mouse leave? because i need to load the data after three second not pre-loaded data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to utilize the `hover()` function to capture when the mouse goes over a particular element and then react as desired when the mouse is removed from that object.

```
$("#someDiv").hover(function(){ 
    //start counter
}, function(){
    //stop counter
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Given this markup:

```
<div id="hoverOverMe">Hover over me</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Something like this plugin should do the trick:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.delayedAction = function(options)
    {
        var settings = $.extend(
            {},
            {
                delayedAction : function(){},
                cancelledAction: function(){},
                hoverTime: 1000               
            },
            options);

        return this.each(function(){
           var $this = $(this);
            $this.hover(function(){  
               $this.data('timerId',
                          setTimeout(function(){
                                      $this.data('hover',false);
                                      settings.delayedAction($this);
                                      },settings.hoverTime));
                $this.data('hover',true);
            },
            function(){        
                if($this.data('hover')){       
                    clearTimeout($this.data('timerId'));
                    settings.cancelledAction($this);
                }
                $this.data('hover',false);
            } );
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

and the calling code:

```
$('#hoverOverMe').delayedAction (
    {
        delayedAction: function($element){
            $('#output').html($element.attr('id') + ' was hovered for 3 seconds');
        },
        cancelledAction: function($element){
            $('#output').html($element.attr('id') + ' was hovered for less than 3 seconds');
        },
        hoverTime: 3000 // 3 seconds
    }
);
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/nrUqS/

For your requirement, something like this should suffice:

```
$('.bean-active').delayedAction(
{ 
   delayedAction: function($element){  
       id_tag = $element.attr("id");   
       $('.bean-bubble,.bean-bubble img').hide();   
       $('#bean-bubble-'+id_tag+',#bean-bubble-'+id_tag+' img').show();
    },
    hoverTime: 3000
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This code will calculate the time in milliseconds that you hover over an element with your mouse:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#element').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(evt) {
    var currentTime == new Date();
    if (evt.type === 'mouseenter') {
        $(this).data('mouseenterTime') == currentTime.getTime();
    } else if (evt.type === 'mouseleave') {
        var mouseoverTime = currentTime.getTime() - $(this).data('mouseenterTime');
        alert('mouseover time was: ' + mouseoverTime);
    }
})
});
```

Comment: I like the way you set up bind.  It makes the logic easy to organize and reuse, but I am getting NAN for mouse over time when I run this function.  Did you get this to work?

Comment: Is it possible to count seconds without mouse leave? because i need to load the data after three second not pre-loaded data.

Answer (score 0):

I've used C. Spencer Beggs answer as a template, because his one didn't work for me. I've used simple variables, included lots of console.log messages and corrected '==' code to '='. This example will wait 3 seconds of 'hover over a link' action to take place before acting. HTH someone.

```
var mouseenterTime = 0;

$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '#element', function (evt)
{
    var currentTime = new Date();
    if (evt.type === 'mouseenter') 
    {
        mouseenterTime = currentTime.getTime();
        console.log('mouseenterTime (#1): ' + mouseenterTime);
    } else if (evt.type === 'mouseleave') {
        console.log('mouseenterTime (#2): ' + mouseenterTime);
        var mouseoverTime = currentTime.getTime() - mouseenterTime;
        console.log('mouseover time was: ' + mouseoverTime);

        // Checking if the Hover action has latest for longer than 3 seconds. 
        if(mouseoverTime > 3000) {console.log("Three seconds have elapsed")}
    }
})
```

Comment: Excellent.  mouseenterTime  needs to be outside of the function.

Comment: Is it possible to count seconds without mouse leave? because i need to load the data after three second not pre-loaded data.