# How to reassign a global variable in a mouse event?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using [jQuery detect how many seconds a mouse stays over element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150219/jquery-detect-how-many-seconds-a-mouse-stays-over-element) to track mouse movement within an HTML element. I send mouseenter and mouseeleave to a Django view. When I print the two values for testing, this is what I get:

```
mouseenterTime: 0, mouseleave: 1629207526636
```

it seems that the mousemovement function doesn't reassign the global variable value. I thought this is because of the loading so I changed the attribute of my external `js` file from `async` to `defer` but that didn't make a difference. What am missing here?
here is the Django view code and the javascript code:

```
def task_view(request ,task):
movement9, created = Movement.objects.get_or_create(participant=participant, svg=svg9)
    if request.method == 'POST':

        mouseenterTime = request.POST.get('mouseenterTime')
        mouseeleaveTime = request.POST.get('mouseeleaveTime')

            if current_svg == str(svg9):
                movement_db = movement9.total_time
                if movement_db == 0: 
                    print("first mouseenterTime: "+ mouseenterTime +", first mouseleave: "+mouseeleaveTime) #here is where I am getting the wrong results hence the rest will be all wrong
                    calculated_seconds = int(mouseeleaveTime) - int(mouseenterTime)
                    movement9.total_time = calculated_seconds
                    movement9.save()
                else: 

                    calculated_seconds = int(mouseeleaveTime) - int(mouseenterTime)
                    movement9.total_time = calculated_seconds + movement_db
                    movement9.save()
```

```js
const server_url = "";
d3.select(window).on('load', function() {

  let mouseenterTime = 0;


  $(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '#gender_question', function(evt) {
    let currentTime = new Date();
    if (evt.type === 'mouseenter') {
      mouseenterTime = currentTime.getTime();

    } else if (evt.type === 'mouseleave') {


      var mouseeleaveTime = currentTime.getTime();
      const data = {
        'svg': 'gender_question',
        'mouseenterTime': mouseenterTime,
        'mouseeleaveTime': mouseeleaveTime
      }
      console.log(data)

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: `${server_url}/study/task_view/Gender/`,
        data: data,
        success() {

        },
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.0.1/d3.min.js" integrity="sha512-1e0JvdNhUkvFbAURPPlFKcX0mWu/b6GT9e0uve7BW4MFxJ15q4ZCd/Llz+B7/oh+qhw7/l6Q1ObPt6aAuR01+Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="gender_question">Some text</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please change it to a [mcve] where you show the issue

Comment: Thanks, but how can I do that with AJAX?

Comment: Console.log the problem vars and explain what you expect to see. Currently your question is not about returned data

Comment: The code seems to work on the version I created for you

Comment: indeed, I think the problem is within the AJAX request. I have added my Django view for clarity. I have multiple elements in which I track the mousemovement, could that be the reason?